# Force volume buttons to always change Media Volume

Tags: htc-evo, volume-control

I want my phone to be on "Vibrate" mode about 99% of the time.  I've found that every time I hit the volume buttons on the side of my Evo, it's either accidental (and I don't want the phone to either go silent mode or ringer mode), or I was trying to control the media volume.

Is there a way to force the phone into interpreting every volume button press as a media volume change, and not a ringer volume change?

Comment: I suspect this is a root-only thing. </speculation>

Comment: @gary if that's true, I'd like to know how :)

Comment: @bryan I was just shooting from the hip. It just sounded like something that wouldn't be available but perhaps more likely on a rooted phone.

Comment: This behaviour of Android is really upsetting me. Why the hell do we need to control 3, 4 types of volumes with the buttons? On Windows or Mac, the volume keys control the "master volume" as they should. I am using tablets, and like the OP, 99.999% time I need to control multimedia volume but if no a/v is playing, pressing the volume keys  controls the damn notification volume, with that annoying beep sound.

Answer (score 4):

There is no setting for this as I'm sure you know. The only way l see this working is if you potentially write an app to capture all volume button changes and then act on the changes from within the app.

You could potentially use **registerMediaButtonEventReceiver** to register your app as a BroadcastReceiver for all media button calls. I say potentially because I'm not 100% sure if this BroadcastReceiver will handle these Intents since I'm purely looking at documentation and haven't actually tried this myself.

Comment: 4 years have passed. Is there any app for that?