# Is it possible to always map volume buttons to media volume?

Tags: volume-control, volume, 7.0-nougat, nexus-6p

I don't use alarm or ring volume. I use vibrations for those, their sound is always always muted, unless I unmuted them by accident.

Sometimes I do want to control media volume when I'm not actually playing any media.

I am aware [the same question exists for another phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2501/force-volume-buttons-to-always-change-media-volume), but it's 5 years old. A lot has changed since then.

Since I use a Nexus 6P running stock Android (Nougat), I'm willing to accept answers that apply only to this specific situation as well.

I haven't rooted my device, so I won't accept any answers requiring that. I do encourage to post answers specificly for rooted devices, so others can find it anyway.

Comment: Changing media volume to a *fixed* level of your choice is possible,

Comment: You can use Tasker in combination with AutoInput plugin. AutoInput can block the system default set to Volume rockers and instead execute your own action. With Tasker you can set it to change media volume.